# Oauth 2.0 Linkedin Client authentication failed

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, client, linkedin-api

I'm trying to connect an account through the Linkedin API, I can't actually understand my mistake with the following [Linkedin official Oauth tutorial](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#permissions).

I get `{'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': 'Client authentication failed'}` in the step 3, when I exchange my code against an access token.

My exact url to post finally data is : `'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken?client_id=86XXXXXl5r7ule&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A8000%2FLinkedin%2Fsignin-linkedin%2F&grant_type=authorization_code&code=AQRT5m_P9wt55p3CZHyHWEem81Csy4V4ubnw8CHumk2yzSm1Q6dj2CoCpcc2buj6yE26_oaayShoQO-59jezPKhXSkaWAeRAyw1u_FMJ-qELW4C5udzwDf5AV36rsDqlev52b79HCxM2GkjzNu2vb4ev7LmVVg&client_secret=55XXXXXlqRF6UvAUJ`

`PARAMETER = {'client_id': '86XXXXXl5r7ule', 
              'redirect_uri': 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Linkedin/signin-linkedin/', 
              'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 
              'code':
'AQRT5m_P9wt55p3CZHyHWEem81Csy4V4ubnw8CHumk2yzSm1Q6dj2CoCpcc2buj6yE26_oaayShoQO-59jezPKhXSkaWAeRAyw1u_FMJ-qELW4C5udzwDf5AV36rsDqlev52b79HCxM2GkjzNu2vb4ev7LmVVg',
              'client_secret': '55XXXXXlqRF6UvAUJ'}`

My code is immediatly send when received, I'm sending all required parameter, avoiding extra parameter, I'm actually receiving the code so I'm able to get resource Owner autorization.

P.S.: `Client_id` and `client_secret` have been checked.
Thanks if anyone have an idea about why I can't get connect as client.

Comment: are you setting the content-type to : Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded ?

Comment: I think it can be something intersting to move on because I don't know what is it, so no I didn't set content type because I don't know how to do that

Comment: Many thank's, the information was under my eyes but I wasn't able to read it because I'm not confortable with HTTP request, thank's for this information, it's also one line in the tutorial

Comment: Can you tell me what was the bugfix, i'm facing same issue.I'm setting content-type too, still getting same error.

Comment: Can you post your answer so that would be useful for others too

Comment: If I remember Well, my http request didn't include "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" so it failed

Comment: u send all parameters in url or in the body?

Comment: i'm using Content-Type but still facing same issue,